# How to include python code direct in sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am writing a py project and use sphinx for the documentation. This is working fine so far.

I know it is possible to include code with something like this:

```
class Foo():
    """Documatation for Foo

    .. code-block:: python

         # Use Foo
         f = Foo()
    """

...
```

I have some larger code sections, which should be included in the documentation. In the upper example, I have the trouble, when e.g. the name of Foo() is changing, I have to change it twice.

Is there a way include something like this in the code?

```
""" ..docu-code-from-hear """

a = 1
b = 2
c = a+b

""" ..docu-code-to-hear """
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want? There is nothing built-in that resembles `docu-code-from-hear` and `docu-code-to-hear`. What would be the result from that? The example has two docstrings, but an object (module, function, class, method) can have only one docstring.

Comment: Ok the 2 docstrings here are missleading. In my real case want 20 lines of code (out of 50 from the whole function) to be included in the documentation. I know that I could just "copy" these lines into a docstring (or an rst file) with the ..code-block:: statement, but with future changes in the code I would always  have to correct the documentation manually... I would like to avoid this manual action.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but have you tried `literalinclude`? https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude?

Comment: `literalinclude` works for the moment. Haven't seen the option to select some lines before. Thanks